# Route value binding to model on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

The title of this post is my best guess at what is happening here. Explanation of what's going on:

On our index page is a list of agents that have been entered into our system. Agents can be entered into our system more than once if they register themselves to sell for multiple companies. In order to streamline the data input process we created a "Clone" feature.

The "Clone" feature works only on agents that have been entered, completely, into our system. By going to the index page, finding an agent in "Complete" status, and clicking the "Clone" link our site will copy a specific set of fields and open up the `Create.cshtml` page with those fields auto-populated.

[image]

When you click the "Clone" link, the site goes into the `Create` `GET` controller. The `PK` of the agent we are cloning from exists in the URL, and we use that in the `GET` controller method to pull the fields we need.

We create a brand new `AgentTransmission` model object, and then post this object to the view. At this point, the model object has a `PK` value of `0` (we use an auto-assigned integer for this field).

[image]

By stepping through the Razor code, I can see that the model posts to the view with the `0` value still there for the `PK` field.

[image]

When you hit "Save", however, the model object posts to the `Create` `POST` controller method with a `PK` value not of `0`, but with the `PK` of the original agent you are cloning from.

[image]

Since the controller, in the `Create` `GET` method, sends a model object to the view with a `PK` value of `0` and, by stepping through the Razor code, I can see that the `Model` that is being rendered in the View still has a `PK` value of `0`, the only place I can see the original Agent's `PK` value coming from is the URL.

[image]

The URL contained in the "Clone" link is formatted like so:

```
{controller}/{action}/{PK}
```

This is the URL that, naturally, appears when the `Create.cshtml` page is rendered. So my question is..:

Is there any way to prevent the `PK` value, which appears in the URL, from being bound to the model object being posted back to the `POST` controller?

If not, can I alter the URL when coming back from the `GET` controller?

**EDIT**

Per comments here are a couple bits or relevant code

**Model**

```
namespace MonetModelFromDb.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AgentTransmission
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
```

**ActionLink from Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Clone", "Create", new { id = item.ID })
```

**GET**

```
    //
    // GET: /AgentTransmission/Create
    [MonetAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Create(int? id, long? x, string l = "", string f = "", string a = "", string agentId = "", bool secondAgent = false, string msg = "", string ReferenceNumber = "")
    {
```

**POST**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MonetAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Create(AgentTransmission agenttransmission, string andAddAgent = "")
    {
```

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative property name on your view model to prevent the ambiguity in the binding? It's hard to see what's actually going on from descriptive prose and lots of screenshots - code would be more useful.

Comment: Understand, not sure what code to show. What would be helpful?

Comment: The view model (irrelevant properties stripped out), GET and POST actions and the relevant parts of the view. Then we can trace the program flow to determine what's bound from where.

Comment: Done, let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful. Thx

Comment: @AntP is correct. You must remove the ambiguity. The modelbinder is not case sensitive so a request parameter of `id` will be bound to a model property of `ID`. All you need to do is change the request param to something like `cloneFromId` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the parameter from `id` to `cloneFromId` and this worked. As mentioned in the comments this was caused by ambiguity between the `PK` field `ID` and the `id` parameter being passed in the URL.